# Is it bad practice for a server to use classes/data structures located on the front end/client?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I’m making a game using React with Socket-io and all the game logic is located directly on the front end.

Each time the player starts a new game, the server also creates a new game. Every time the client moves, it sends the action to the server and the server updates it’s own copy of the game based on the players actions. This is to detect any cheating.

The only issue is that all the game logic is located on the front end, so the server must import the files and classes from the front end directory.

Say the user modifies game logic in devtools, would it affect the servers copies of the objects/files? Is it necessary to move the game logic onto the server and have the front end import the classes? Or making a copy of all the files for the server to have as well as the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, clients will not be able to change server logic anyhow. I don't think you should worry about that in your case. Even if someone changes something in dev tools, it will only be available locally on their machine. And your cheat detection system should be able to catch it.

The server still uses server files even when you load them from "from the front end directory." This is still server data and not the client as you are importing or bundling it all on the server.

However, if those files are used in both the client and the server, it might be better to move them to "shared" (instead of keeping them all together in "frontend") directory. Just to make it more obvious and have more rules/guarantees for this directory.

You have a much bigger problem if you allow any clients to change code on the server in general.

Comment: "....it will only be available locally on their machine", Right I thought so, I was more worried about how to setup the files directory since it didn't seem right having the server import files in a whole other directory. I think I will move all the game logic (classes, datastructures) into the directory that the server/frontend are contained in, thanks.